# TCPDF Different Header and Footer in different section

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a php file generating pdf file using tcpdf.
I have 2 sections in the pdf file.

- Both section has different header and footer.
- Data in both section might overflow to the next page.

How do I make 2 different section to have its own header and footer?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to have 2 different header for different section without having to generate 2 pdf file and then merge the file.

set this on the end of the first section:
    `$pdf->lastPage();`

set this on the beginning of the second section:
    `$pdf->setHeaderData('', 0, 'secondheader', '');`
    `$pdf->AddPage('P','mm',$pagelayout);`

set this in customer header function:
    `$header_data = $this->getHeaderData();`
    `if ($header_data['title'] == "secondheader") {`
      `// use this header`
    `} else {`
      `// use this header`
    `}`